# An easy way to mock loosely defined Python dict objects

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-mock, python-unittest

Is there an easy way to mock loosely defined dict objects in Python?  For example, how can I easily express that given a dict `input`, I want to check whether or not each value in it conforms to a particular meta-definition, like minimum and maximum values, lengths, and types?

Being able to do this could be handy, for example, when writing tests.

In [mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) ([unittest.mock](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock) in Python versions 3.3+) one can specify that a value can be [`ANY`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock#any) value, like in

```
>>> mock = Mock(return_value=None)
>>> mock('foo', bar=object())
>>> mock.assert_called_once_with('foo', bar=ANY)
```

However, what if `bar` above should be a dict-like object, like

```
>>> {'baz': <an integer between -3 and 14>, 'qux': <'yes' or 'no'>}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've actually written [AnyValid](https://github.com/mtr/AnyValid), a minimal library that leverages the great work implemented in [formencode](http://www.formencode.org/) and [unittest.mock](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock), to handle such cases.

For example, testing a dict object like described above, can then be expressed as

```
>>> from mock import Mock
>>> from any_valid import AnyValid, Int, OneOf
>>> valid_bar = {
...     'baz': AnyValid(Int(min=-3, max=14)),
...     'qux': AnyValid(OneOf(['yes', 'no'])),
...     }
>>> mock = Mock(return_value=None)
>>> mock('foo', bar={'baz': 4, 'qux': 'yes'})
>>> mock.assert_called_once_with('foo', bar=valid_bar)
>>>
```

Because AnyValid is can take any validator from the large set of validators in formencode, many other conditions can be specified in a similarly expressive manner.

Comment: 9 minutes to write a library, nice